# Make the input data into regular data

Tags: excel

If I have the data "-AB" in a cell and then I press the enter button, I retrieve an error message.

The goal is to make the data "-AB" as a regular data without using any function or usage for math. Just regular data only.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions

1. Use a hyphen, enter '-AB instead of -AB
2. Format the cell as text **before** you enter -AB

Comment: Thank you for your help!